# Main page News Posts - Auto Zoom and Dimensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, carousel

Our main page in intranet is currently on Carousel view. I make my graphics in Canvas on 1980x1080 resolution. When I upload the graphics, it auto zooms-in and I can't determine how to make the graphics so that I don't have to go back and forth to adjust the graphics.

The question - what dimensions should I put my Canvas graphics at, or how should i create a graphic that wont get cut off?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend consulting Microsoft's documentation on image sizing for modern pages:

[Image sizing and scaling in SharePoint modern pages](https://support.microsoft.com/office/image-sizing-and-scaling-in-sharepoint-modern-pages-dc510065-b5a5-4654-bc94-e3ecbbb57d8d)